# How to mock only some mutaions in the apollo gateway?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-gateway

I have an `apollo-gateway` service that I initialize using a composed schema. How can I override only some mutations and queries in this gateway service? So it will use underlying services for all queries and mutations except for some specific queries or mutations that I have overridden in the gateway?